# GoogleCredential OAuth access token invalid_grant error

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to acquire a 2 legged oauth2 access token for google's storage api through a service account.

The relevant documentation is contained here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I first tried attempted to acquire the token through their HTTP/REST api. I eventually gave up being unable to get past a 400 response with the following details:

> { "error" : "invalid_grant" }

I then turned to the recommended method: using the java Google api client library (I'm using scala).

```
val credentialBuilder = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
  .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
  .setServiceAccountId(Configuration.GoogleAPI.ServiceAccount.email)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(Configuration.GoogleAPI.ServiceAccount.pkcs12))
  .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL))

def updateToken = {
  val credential = credentialBuilder.build()
  credential.refreshToken()
  // ... do stuff here with token
}
```

Running the above, I get a TokenResponseException, with a payload identical to the error I was getting directly accessing the REST api. 400 Bad Request, invalid_grant error.

Doing some research (on both stackoverflow and elsewhere), I find that the most common reasons for this error message are:

1) The local clock is not synced with Google's servers. I suspected this even back when I was using the REST api because I've encountered this issue for other services before. I'm fairly sure its not a clock issue however, because I have repeatedly synced my clocks with an external ntp server:

> sudo ntpdate -s ntp.ubuntu.com

2) The other common cause for this error is setting the service account client ID incorrectly. Most people set it to their service account client id (ending with "apps.googleusercontent.com") instead of their service account client email. Its pretty clear that this isn't the problem, since I'm correctly pointing to the email (the docs instructed this, so I followed the directions), ending with "@developer.gserviceaccount.com".

I'm stuck. I've checked the user documentation, the javadocs, various forums. The error message isn't very helpful (probably designed that way, since it's a security endpoint).

**What other possible causes for this error exist? What can I do to get my service account access token?**

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OAuth2.0 to access a google analytics account then there could be one more reason of getting invalid_grant. As per [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication#invalid-grant):

> If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, an
>   invalid_grant error response is returned. The limit for each unique
>   pair of OAuth 2.0 client and Google Analytics account is 25 refresh
>   tokens (note that this limit is subject to change). If the application
>   continues to request refresh tokens for the same Client/Account pair,
>   once the 26th token is issued, the 1st refresh token that was
>   previously issued will become invalid. The 27th requested refresh
>   token would invalidate the 2nd previously issued token and so on.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem.

I'm not using the analytics service (though it's possible this applies to other apis as well).
I haven't even successfully acquired an access token once, nevermind refreshing an existing token. No one else is using this service account.
If this were a problem, I would be able to get a token after waiting an hour for the old token to expire. I haven't been able to get a token even after not attempting to acquire one for more than an hour.